# C++ winsock TCP listening

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, winsock

I have a software that decodes ADS-B messages (from planes) and sends results in hexadecimal to a port (47806).

I would like to listen to this port to show that data, so I wrote this :

```
WSADATA WSAData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), & WSAData);

SOCKET sock;
SOCKADDR_IN socket_in;
socket_in.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
socket_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_in.sin_port = htons(47806);
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)& socket_in, sizeof(socket_in));

listen(sock, 0);
int valid = 0;
while (TRUE) {
    int size_socket_in = sizeof(socket_in);
    valid = accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)& socket_in, & size_socket_in);

    if (valid != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "OK";
    }
}
```

This code should display "OK" each time a message is received, but it doesn't.
I can read data with a Telnet software, like PuTTY :
[PuTTY telnet on port 47806](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgHCT.png)

I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: UDP isn't connection based, `listen()` will fail and `accept()` will as well. Also, telnet is a TCP service.

Comment: @Hasturkun I just checked with `netstat`, it's effectively a TCP connection. So I updated my post with a new code. Thank you

Comment: You got the "listening" concept backwards; your ADS-B process listens on port 47806, in your client app you just need to connect to localhost, port 47806 and you'll get your messages sent to you via that connection.

Comment: @RustyX It's my first use of sockets, so I'm a little bit lost. So, I defined the ip address with `InetPton`, I use the `connect` function instead of `bind` and `recv` instead of `accept`. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the right code :

```
WSADATA WSAData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), & WSAData);

SOCKET sock;
SOCKADDR_IN socket_in;
InetPton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", & socket_in.sin_addr.s_addr);
socket_in.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket_in.sin_port = htons(47806);
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)& socket_in, sizeof(socket_in));

int valid = 0;
char buffer[512] = "";
while (TRUE) {
    valid = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    if (valid != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << buffer;
    }
}
```

My program is a **client** and not a server. So I have to define an IP adress with `InetPton`, connect to the server with `connect` and receive the messages with `recv`.

Thank you @Hasturkun and @RustyX for help and explanations.